# Strange error in python using SMTPLIB module

Tags: python, email, smtplib

still having issues. I just added some code which uses the smtplib module to send an email to the email address that has been entered by the user, however I got this error

> File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 555, in login
>       raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
>   SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

The code I used was from a beginners website

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)


server.login("youremailusername", "password")
msg = "\nHello!"
server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
```

However in my case, I used the name of a variable which holds the email or the user where it says "target @example.com" Help someone? ALso I would like to know what are the numbers that come after "smtp.gmail.com"? The 587?

Comment: unfortunately gmail does not support smtplib

Comment: its not true gmail support smtplib

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this `server.starttls()` before `login`

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()         
server.login("youremailusername", "password")
msg = "\nHello!"
server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
```

`starttls` put the SMTP connection in `TLS (Transport Layer security)`

Comment: Worked like a champ!